# How do I change DatePickerDialog default date to an user latest selected date?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I kinda stuck with this problem.
I have created a DatePickerDialog in a fragment. I set the default date to be the current date when the user is opening the calendar for the first time. When the dialog is dismissed, I'm setting the EditText with the date the user have chosen.
But when the user opens the date picker dialog again, it stays at the default date. I want when the user opens the dialog again to show latest selected date. What would be the best approach to this problem?

The DatePickerFragment file:

```kotlin
    class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(),
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    
        override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, day)
            datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = c.timeInMillis
            return datePickerDialog
        }
    
        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
            val date = DateUtils.formatToBirthdayString(year, month, dayOfMonth)
            parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
                KEY_BIRTH_DATE,
                Bundle().apply { putString(KEY_BIRTH_DATE, date) }
            )
        }
    }
```

BirthdayDialogCommand file:

```kotlin
class BirthdayDialogCommand(private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : Command {

    override fun execute() {
        val picker = DatePickerFragment()

        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(BirthdayDialogCommand::class.java.simpleName) == null) {
            picker.show(fragmentManager, BirthdayDialogCommand::class.java.simpleName)
        }
    }
}
```

And the DetailsFragment file:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        
        ................................

        setDataBinding()
        setDataListeners()

        return binding.root
    }



    private fun setDataBinding() {
        binding.apply {
            
            ................................

            birthdayCommand = BirthdayDialogCommand(
                parentFragmentManager
            )
    }

    private fun setDataListeners() {


        ................................


        parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
            KEY_BIRTH_DATE,
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            patientDataListener
        )

    }

 private val patientDataListener = FragmentResultListener { _, bundle ->
        bundle.getString(KEY_BIRTH_DATE)?.let {
            binding.birthday.text = it
            patientViewModel.setPatientBirthday(it)
        }

        ................................
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DatePickerFragment class

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(),
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

// Add a variable to keep the user selected date
var selectedDate: String? = null


override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()

    if (selectedDate != null) {
        // You need to specify the date format are you using, in this example is "dd/MM/yyyy"
        val dateUserSelected = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(selectedDate!!)
        // The calendar instance has now the date selected by the user
        c.setTime(date)
    }
    
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, day)
    datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = c.timeInMillis
    return datePickerDialog
}

override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    val date = DateUtils.formatToBirthdayString(year, month, dayOfMonth)
    parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
        KEY_BIRTH_DATE,
        Bundle().apply { putString(KEY_BIRTH_DATE, date) }
    )
}
```

Now, you need provide the user selected date

```
class BirthdayDialogCommand(private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : Command {

override fun execute() {
    val picker = DatePickerFragment()
    // It must be set before the .show method
    picker.selectedDate = editTextWithTheDate.getText().toString()
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(BirthdayDialogCommand::class.java.simpleName) == null) {
        picker.show(fragmentManager, BirthdayDialogCommand::class.java.simpleName)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the system creates that dialog to display it, it runs the code in `onCreateDialog` which is where you're setting the dialog up. You're explicitly setting the date to "today" when you do that, so it's always going to default to that.

When you get a value you want to keep and reference later, you need to store it somewhere - the usual way is in `SharedPreferences`. That way, when you come to display your dialog, you can check if there's a value stored - if so, use it! If not, fall back to your default.

Exactly how you want to do this is up to you - since you're pulling `day`, `month` and `year` `int`s from the `Calendar`, you might just want to store each of those

```
with(prefs.edit()) {
    putInt(KEY_BIRTHDAY_DAY, day)
    putInt(KEY_BIRTHDAY_MONTH, month)
    ...
    apply()
}
```

and you can use `getInt` with a default value like -1 to pull the values back out - if any of them aren't a valid number (e.g. -1) then you don't have a date stored!

Here's some stuff on `SharedPreferences`, there's a few ways to use them - you can provide a name to create a prefs file specifically for handling your stored data if you want:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: I think I get it how SharedPreferences works, but I will be glad if you show me some simple and easy to understand example. Sorry if asking too much, I'm still new with Kotlin.